# Mapped object type with generic per key in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a type that is any array of two items: a list of parameters and a function with arguments that matches the parameters. To make it easy, I've created a function that can infer the generic type.

```
type MapParamsToFunction<A extends any[]> = [[...params: A], (...args: A) => void]

function asMap<A extends any[]>(map: MapParamsToFunction<A>): MapParamsToFunction<A> {
    return map;
}

asMap([[],() => {}]) // good
asMap([[0, "Hello World", 2], (a: number, b: string, c: number) => { }]); // good
asMap([[0, "Hello World", 2], (a: number, b: number, c: number) => { }]); // error
asMap([[0, "Hello World"], (a: number, b: string, c: number) => { }]); // error
```

No problem so far. Now, I want to take this and create a dictionary where each key can have a different list of parameters/arguments. However, I don't see a way to have TypeScript use a different generic on each key.

I've tried using `any[]` on the type, but it will not throw a type error if the parameters don't match the arguments.

```
type FunctionDictionary<T extends string> = {
    [K in T]: MapParamsToFunction<any[]>
}

function asDictionary<T extends string>(dict: FunctionDictionary<T>): FunctionDictionary<T> {
    return dict;
}

let obj = asDictionary({
    "foo": [[0, "Hello World", 2], (a: number, b: number, c: number) => { }], // no type error
    "bar": [["","",""], (a: string, b: string, c: string) => { }]
});
```

Is there a way to map this, so each argument can have it's own generic parameter list?

```
type FunctionDictionary<T extends string> = {
    [K in T]: MapParamsToFunction<?> // <--- what goes here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have [existential types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) to say "a `MapParamsToFunction<X>` for *some* type `X`", so you can't just make `FunctionDictionary` a record of those.  Luckily, it does allow [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types), so you can take an *object type* `T` whose properties are all argument lists, and map each property `K` to an appropriate `MapParamsToFunction<T[K]>`:

```
type FunctionDictionary<T extends Record<keyof T, any[]>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: MapParamsToFunction<T[K]>
}
```

Then your `asDictionary()` will infer the `T` object from a passed-in `FunctionDictionary<T>` like this:

```
function asDictionary<T extends Record<keyof T, any[]>>(
    dict: FunctionDictionary<T>
): FunctionDictionary<T> {
    return dict;
}
```

And you get the behavior you want:

```
let obj = asDictionary({
    "foo": [[0, "Hello World", 2], (a: number, b: number, c: number) => { }], // error!
    // --------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Types of parameters 'b' and 'args_1' are incompatible.
    "bar": [["", "", ""], (a: string, b: string, c: string) => { }]
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmACnATnAtgZwCoHsBiArgHYDGwAlrsQDwCCUEAHsBMQCaZRzEgDaAXQB8UALxQ+fAHQywqDJgBcUOgIA0UABQypqAOZKVASjEiAbrgrsBAKBsAzEuSrFumeGHqMWbTt16CQproCMoeyGhYeERklNT0QkZhCBEK0U5xtHQiAN42UAVQKBDAhCiuIWAA3DYAvnZw7giakgAMGgBEABIQADa9uFAA6rgovewdGgBM6lpwysSE6ABGECgay8qYwCgUxHoapAtLqygmorlQtQJGVVAA9PdQeri47DaNHi187VDdfQNhqNxpMoDMNJp5lBFis1htjrD1lAjtCTmtzpdrrcHk81ihRnZQJAoDFnNQACIUMnEVAgGjYbysDhcABKEFIo3YNAA1hAQLh7FBsBoePxhCJxHlChIANJQPZQXn8wXYATJJDyKIEDIuel8GXCOp2RyxFxuSnU2n0xm+Vnszk8vkCoUigLizT5QrsKnAZSkzIWzJW7BCGxJEk6ik+lzB3KegrFUrlKDe8g1eo2XolKC4ZYAKzE5uj1FpmilhQ69leHWUbU6PX6gxGYwm01mkIRp3hqMRh076NMUByV1mj0YKHxKAAhPGcVAALSLpfLlerlciAB+W+3O93e-3B53s7H2HAEC4zrkkRKay4AHJlnf-OwoHf9JgAPoARifqGgew5dA5EoZYsykWcOmWVAawkPgOlBeDOg6dsoW2XZ9m7NC9gOZEth2bCMSHEc6luIA)

Comment: Your answer here helped me figure out how to solve a different but related problem around parametrizing an `api` object where the keys are method names and the values are fetcher functions like `(p: Params) => Promise<Response>`. The example showing that `T` could reference itself in `T extends Record<keyof T, any[]>` was especially helpful. Thanks! 
https://twitter.com/davidcrespo/status/1380555171130920961