# Constrained arbitrary types in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a type that is like so:

```js
type Communication<C,R> = { 
  send: (config: C) => R;
  receive: (returnType: R) => void;
}
```

The key point is that there's some typed parameter `C` to the `send` function, which returns some other type `R`. Then, the `receive` function's argument is the return type of the send function (`R`).

I want to be able to make a type that doesn't care about the type of `R` and `C`, say:

```js
// This doesn't compile of course
type CommunicationMap = Record<string, Communication>
```

such that I can declare:

```js
// I want this to compile
const ideal: CommunicationMap = {
 "withReturnTypeNumber": {
     send: (config: SomeType) => 4;
     receive: (result: number) => {}
  },
  "withReturnTypeString": {
     send: (config: DifferentConfigTypeAlltogether) => "this one returns a string";
     receive: (result: string) => {} 
  }
}
```

Where each key of the `ideal` object satisfies `Communication<C,R>` with arbitrary `C` and `R`, but I don't have to declare ahead of time which `C` and `R` will be assigned to which key. That is, the above object would compile, but the following object would not:

```js
// I want this not to compile
const ideallyThisDoesNotCompile: CommunicationMap = {
 "withReturnTypeNumber": {
     send: (config: SomeType) => 4;
     receive: (result: string) => {} // string is not number
  },
}
```

---

@kaya3 linked a question that has a partial answer. Following the pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343641/mapped-object-type-with-generic-per-key-in-typescript), we can do:

```js
type Send<C,R> = (config: C) => R;
type Receive<R> = (data: R) => void;
type Communication<C,R> = {
  send: Send<C,R>;
  receive: Receive<R>;
}

type MappedCommunication<F extends Send<any, any>> = Communication<Parameters<F>[0], ReturnType<F>>

type CommunicationMap<T extends Record<keyof T, Communication<any,any>>> = {
   [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Communication<infer C, infer R> ? Communication<C,R> : never;
}

const communication = <F extends Send<any,any>>(
  send: F,
  receive: (args: ReturnType<F>) => void,
): Communication<Parameters<F>[0], ReturnType<F>> => ({
  send,
  receive,
});

const communicationMap = <T extends Record<keyof T, Communication<any,any>>>(map: CommunicationMap<T>): CommunicationMap<T> => map;
```

[ts playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgvJBW)

However, that doesn't work, because:

```
const ideallyThisDoesNotCompile = communicationMap({
  withReturnTypeNumber: communication(
   (config: number) => 4,
   (result: string) => {}, // number is not assignable to type string, good
  ),
  withOtherReturnTypeNumber: { // if you omit the function here
   send: (config: number) => 4,
   receive: (result: string) => {}, // then this compiles, but it shouldn't, bad
  },
});
```

Ideally, I'd like to not require the functions - they'd be easy to forget, and this is a type in the config object for a library, so I'd like the exposed types to be as useful as possible.

Is there a way to do this? (solutions that change the definition of `Communication` and `CommunicationMap` are allowed)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mA8lkN) solve your problem? If yes, I will write up an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapped object type with generic per key in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343641/mapped-object-type-with-generic-per-key-in-typescript)

Comment: Thanks @wonderflame. It does answer the question, although I am hoping to do it without needing extra functions. Since it's a different approach to the other linked answer, I think it's worth writing up

Comment: Thanks @kaya3! I'll check it out and see if I can modify it for my usecase

Comment: Ah, @wonderflame - I have `strictFunctionTypes`, enabled which prevents that approach from working. The reason I have that set is because otherwise [these](https://tsplay.dev/wj0G8m) invalid objects will compile

Comment: @kaya3 - although that question is definitely related, the answer doesn't solve this case - see my edits